# Deleting outside the insert region in Vim

Tags: vim

You can stop the backspace key from deleting characters that precede the start of the insert region using:

> :set backspace=

Is there a similar setting that stops the delete key from deleting characters that follow the insert region?

To understand my question, consider editing a line that contains only `ABC`.  Start with the backspace setting at its default value:

> :set backspace=indent,eol,start

Place the cursor on the `B` and press `i` to enter insert mode.  Then hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.  The `A` is deleted.  Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>u</kbd> to undo the change.  Then change the backspace setting with:

> :set backspace=

Repeat the process.  The `A` is no longer deleted. Now go into insert mode again, but this time press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.  The `B` disappears.  That is what I want to stop from happening.  Now, press <kbd>Shift+Backspace</kbd>.  This deletes the `C` key.  I also want that to stop.  In this case shift-backspace is acting like delete, but there is no mapping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, as you can see from `:help 'backspace'`, all you have is `indent`, `eol`, `start`, and `nostop`, so I'm afraid what you want can't be done easily.

Comment: The ```backspace``` is dedicated to controlling what happens on the left side of the region.  I am having a hard time accepting that they did not provide a way of doing the same thing for the right side of the region.

Comment: You can make a feature request.